# Your fitness function must return a scalar value

Tags: matlab, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, scalar, fitness

I tried to perform an optimization using a neural network and the genetic algorithm.  I trained a neural network with **input p (4x72 matrix)** and **target t (2x72 matrix)**. Regrading the optimization using genetic algorithm, I used the `sim` function of the neural network as the fitness function.  The code I used for it is as follows:

```
objFcn=@(p) sim(net,p');
%'net' is the neural network I created with p as input and t as target
[xOpt,fVal,exitflag,target]=ga(objFcn,4,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options);
```

I have provided the LB and UB which are lower bound and upper bounds, respectively. And `options`, I tried it with

```
options = gaoptimset('Vectorized','on');
% even vectorized off doesnt solve the problem
```

Logically, as I used **p'** in the `sim` command, the resultant matrix would be **72x2** which is the same as the population for GA. But for some reason, I always get the error saying 'Your fitness function must return a scalar value'.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "sim" function returns a matrix with all outputs from your network. You need to compute the squared error from that in order to provide a scalar value to minimize with the GA.

Comment: do you mean by calculating mean squared error, i end up in a 1x1 matrix which obviously becomes a scalar? I tried it with just1 output and the method I said works perfect. Since I am considering 3 outputs, I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: Icreated a function mse_c with the code as follows:

function mse_calc = mse_c(net, p, t)
y=sim(net,p);
mse_calc = sum((y-t).^2)/length(y);
end

This function returns a 72x1 matrix. But to feed it as a fitness function in GA, it has to be 1x72 as far as i know. The transpose sign would render some error in the function.